# Blazor Components Masonry

Tags: c#, blazor

Хотел бы узнать, имеются ли какие-нибудь UI компоненты для Blazor, чтобы можно было построить сетку фотографий как в Pinterest без использования Masonry library (https://masonry.desandro.com/) ?
Или же есть уже какая-нибудь готовая реализация этому